# winform picturebox не отображает JPEG byte из SQL

Tags: c#, ado.net

этот код отображает фото из датабейз Nortwind из таблицы Categories

другие данные отображается, но фотки нет.
Ошибка "parametr is not valid"
код этот в ADO.NET c#

```
   private void DisplayDatabaseImageForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // create the DataSet
        ds = new DataSet();

        // create the DataAdapter and retrieve the Employees table
        String selectCommand = "SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName FROM Employees";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ADMIN-ПК\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True");

        da = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand,con);
        da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, "Employees");
        da.Fill(ds, "Employees");

        // bind several table fields to controls
        employeeIdTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Employees.EmployeeID");
        lastNameTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Employees.LastName");
        firstNameTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Employees.FirstName");

        // get the binding manager base for the Employees table
        bm = BindingContext[ds, "Employees"];
        // update the image in response to each record reposition
        bm.PositionChanged += new EventHandler(bm_PositionChanged);
        // update the display for the first record
        bm_PositionChanged(null, null);
    }

    private void bm_PositionChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // refresh the photo displayed when the current record changes

        // get the new EmployeeID using the BindingManager
        int employeeId = (int)ds.Tables["Employees"].Rows[bm.Position]["EmployeeID"];

        // create a connection
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ADMIN-ПК\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True");
        // create a command to retrieve the employee photo
        String sqlText = "SELECT Photo FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID=" + employeeId;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlText, conn);

       // retrieve the employee photo to a stream
        conn.Open();
        Byte[] image = (Byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar(); ;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image);
        conn.Close();

        // load the image into the PictureBox from the stream
        photoPictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        ms.Close();
    }
```

Comment: На эту строку `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image);` поставьте точку останова, и посмотрите значение переменной `image`, что там?

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
private void bm_PositionChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image tmp = photoPictureBox.Image;
    int employeeId = (int)ds.Tables["Employees"].Rows[bm.Position]["EmployeeID"];
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ADMIN-ПК\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Photo FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @employeeId", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeId", employeeId);
            photoPictureBox.Image = ByteToImage((byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        }
    }
    if (tmp != null) { tmp.Dispose(); tmp = null; }
}
public Image ByteToImage(byte[] value)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(value)) { return Image.FromStream(mStream); }
    }
    else { return null; }
}
```

Проверьте, действительно ли тут [(byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar()] возвращается массив байтов, или там null. Вообще ставьте точки останова и смотрите по строчкам что у вас, где и как происходит. Всё в порядке с employeeId? такая запись с таким employeeId есть? всё в порядке с возвращаемым массивом байтов? всё в порядке с Image.FromStream(mStream)? это действительно изображение? Не стесняйтесь использовать try/catch и ловить ошибки.