# Преобразовать код изображения из базы MSSQL в pictureBox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server, picturebox

Имеется таблица в MSSQL с колонкой типа **Varbinary(max)**

С помощью запроса я конвертировала **Varbinary(max)** в **Nvarchar(max)**, чтобы получить строку в C#.

```
select name, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),img, 1)
from a1
```

Вот пример кода изображения, точнее его начало, строка очень длинная.

```
0xFFD8FFE1858C4578696600004D4D002A00000008000F0
```

---

Вопрос 1. Что это за код изображения? Бинарный?

Вопрос 2. Как этот код преобразовать и вывести в **pictureBox**?

---

Вот что пробовала:

```
 img1 = img1.Substring(2);
 Bitmap bitImage = bitmap(img1);
 imgAptPicBox.Image = bitImage;

    public Bitmap bitmap(string Image)
    {

        byte[] imageBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Image);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
        {
            return new Bitmap(ms);
        }
    }
```

А ещё вот так:

```
Byte[] bitmapData = Convert.FromBase64String(FixBase64ForImage(img));
System.IO.MemoryStream streamBitmap = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bitmapData);
Bitmap bitImage = new Bitmap((Bitmap)Image.FromStream(streamBitmap));
imgAptPicBox.Image = bitImage;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вопрос 1. Что это за код изображения? Бинарный?

Обычная HEX-строка.

> Вопрос 2. Как этот код преобразовать и вывести в pictureBox?

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromHexString(img.SubString(2));
using var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
```

---

Лучше конечно не преобразовывать в строку, а читать сразу в двоичном формате - [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1044015/373567).

Comment: Желательно бы привести пример без преобразования в Hex и обратно, так как ADO.NET позволяет это сделать (SqlDataReader.GetBytes). Делать преобразование в NVARCHAR тут нет никакой необходимости. И возможно где-то уже есть ответ, как все это делать правильно.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight я бы с удовольствием, но ADO.NET не знаю

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight вы можете помочь мне, дополнить ответ или дать свой, а я удалю? Как я понял, что это [как-то так](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-binary-data) делается.

Comment: Выглядит логично код, но возникла ошибка  "Convert не содержит FromHexString", пытаюсь найти решение в интернете

Comment: @AngelinaLoseva версия .NET какая? Если используете устаревшую версию, всегда ее указывайте. А еще лучше, если возможно, пересоздайте приложение под .NET 6

Comment: версия .NET  Framework 4.8

Comment: @AngelinaLoseva ну да, так и есть - версия старая. Вам нужно для нее решение, или перенесете код в проект для новой версии .NET? Тогда этот код заработает как есть.

Comment: попробую новый создать сейчас

Comment: @AngelinaLoseva https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMs2p.png

Comment: Да, действительно работает, сейчас подключила БД и проверила! Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Удалять нет смысла, в текущей формулировке вопроса это правильный ответ. Можно сослаться на этот вопрос, где показано, как выгружать массив напрямую: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1044015/240512 , или на документацию по вашей ссылке.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight спасибо, добавил ссылку в ответ.